# Can someone please explain what the line for(;Q.size();) does?

Tags: c++, stl, deque, que

I am trying to understand a source code and i cannot figure out how the line `for(;Q.size();)` is meant to work. Could someone please simplify it for me ?

Comment: It's the same as `while(Q.size())`.

Comment: Or more clearly, `while(!Q.empty())`

Answer (score 2):

A [`for` statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) consists of three parts, separated by semicolons:

- an *init-statement*
- a *condition*
- an *iteration_expression*

A `for` loop is equivalent to this code:

```
{
    init_statement 
    while ( condition ) { 
        statement 
        iteration_expression ; 
    }
}
```

The *init-statement* and *iteration_expression* can be empty, but the semicolons between them are still required.

In your example, `for(;Q.size();)` would thus be equivalent to:

```
{
    while ( Q.size() ) { 
        statement 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way:

`for(<do nothing>;Q.size();<do nothing>) {//do something}`

Now read the definition of the `for` loop and see that it fits perfectly.
As mentioned by others, essentially this becomes equivalent to `while(Q.size())`

Answer (score 0):

It's a `for` loop which doesn't care about an incrementing index variable. As Blaze pointed out it's equivalent to a `while` loop.

```
for(;Q.size();)
{
   // do something while Q is not empty
}
```

or equivalently

```
while(Q.size())
{
   // do something while Q is not empty
}
```